# how to stop ajax run multiple time?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.0

i am using cakephp framework 2.0. I don't know why my ajax run multiple time. i have created dynamic element so that' why i used this click function

```
$(document).on('click','.save',function(){ });
```

[image]

Now you can see the picture here is my Jquery and ajax code:-

```
enter code here
$(document).on('click','.save',function(){
        var user_id = "<?= $user_id; ?>";
        var rowid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        var saveNameOrg = $(this).attr('name').split('_');          
        var saveName = saveNameOrg[0];
        var carePlanid = saveNameOrg[1];
        //$("input[name=nameGoesHere]").val();
        var yn_value = $('input[name="data['+saveName+']['+"'y_n'"+']"]').is(":checked"); 
        var green_value = $('input[name="data['+saveName+']['+"'green'"+']"]').val(); 
        var orange_value = $('input[name="data['+saveName+']['+"'orange'"+']"]').val(); 
        var red_value = $('input[name="data['+saveName+']['+"'red'"+']"]').is(":checked");
        var alert_value = $('input[name="data['+saveName+']['+"'alert'"+']"]').is(":checked"); 

            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'/app/webroot/CeyHello/doctors/custom_plan_new_ajax',
                data:{ user_id: user_id,yn:yn_value, green: green_value, orange: orange_value, red: red_value, alert: alert_value, question_id: saveName, carePlanid: carePlanid },
                success:function(resp){
                    if(resp == "success"){
                        alert("Data Saved");
                    }

                },
                error:function(){

                }

            });

    });
```

here is my button :-

```
enter code here
<td><a href="javascript:;" id="<?php echo $result['cq_id'];?>" class="save" name="<?php echo $result['cq_id']."_".$carePlansList['EveCarePlansList']['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a></td>
```

My Html data:-

```
enter code here
    <?php 
    if(isset($carePlansList['EveChfQuestion'])){
    if(!empty($carePlansList['EveChfQuestion'])){
    foreach($carePlansList['EveChfQuestion'] as $key => $result) { ?>
        <?php if(in_array($result['cq_id'], $editedQuesIds)) { foreach($eveChfQuesUser as $editQues) { 
            if($editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['q_id'] == $result['cq_id']) {
        ?>
        <tr id="row_<?=$editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['q_id']?>">
            <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-file-archive-o"></i></th>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbx">
                    <input name="data[<?php echo $editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['q_id']; ?>]['y_n']" id="checkbox0" type="checkbox" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox0"></label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><?=$editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['cq_question'] ?></td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline checkbx">
                    <input id="inlineCheckbox2" name="data[<?php echo $editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['q_id']; ?>]['green']" type="checkbox" value="Y" <?php if($editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['green_high_value'] != "") echo "checked"; ?>>
                    <label for="inlineCheckbox2">Y</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-pink checkbox-inline checkbx">
                    <input name="data[<?php echo $editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['q_id']; ?>]['green']"  id="checkbox0" type="checkbox" value="N" <?php if($editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['green_low_value'] != "") echo "checked"; ?>>
                    <label for="checkbox0">N</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline checkbx">
                    <input name="data[<?php echo $editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['q_id']; ?>]['orange']"  id="inlineCheckbox2" type="checkbox" value="Y" <?php if($editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['orange_high_val'] != "") echo "checked"; ?>>
                    <label for="inlineCheckbox2">Y</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-pink checkbox-inline checkbx">
                    <input name="data[<?php echo $editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['q_id']; ?>]['orange']"  id="checkbox0" type="checkbox" value="N" <?php if($editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['orange_low_value'] != "") echo "checked"; ?>>
                    <label for="checkbox0">N</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbx">
                    <input name="data[<?php echo $editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['q_id']; ?>]['red']"  id="inlineCheckbox2" type="checkbox" <?php if($editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['red_high_val'] != "") echo "checked"; ?>>
                    <label for="inlineCheckbox2">Y</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbx">
                    <input name="data[<?php echo $editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['q_id']; ?>]['alert']"  id="inlineCheckbox2" type="checkbox" <?php if($editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['alert_ind'] == "1") echo "checked"; ?>>
                    <label for="inlineCheckbox2">Y</label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:;" class="save" name="<?php echo $editQues['EveChfQuestionsUser']['q_id']."_".$editQues['EveCarePlansList']['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a></td>
       </tr>
        <?php } } } else{ ?>

            <tr id="row_<?=$result['cq_id']?>">
                <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-file-archive-o"></i></th>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbx">
                        <input name="data[<?php echo $result['cq_id']; ?>]['y_n']" id="checkbox0" type="checkbox" >
                        <label for="checkbox0"></label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><?=$result['cq_question'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline checkbx">
                        <input id="inlineCheckbox2" name="data[<?php echo $result['cq_id']; ?>]['green']" type="checkbox" value="Y">
                        <label for="inlineCheckbox2">Y</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-pink checkbox-inline checkbx">
                        <input name="data[<?php echo $result['cq_id']; ?>]['green']"  id="checkbox0" type="checkbox" value="N">
                        <label for="checkbox0">N</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline checkbx">
                        <input name="data[<?php echo $result['cq_id']; ?>]['orange']"  id="inlineCheckbox2" type="checkbox" value="Y">
                        <label for="inlineCheckbox2">Y</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-pink checkbox-inline checkbx">
                        <input name="data[<?php echo $result['cq_id']; ?>]['orange']"  id="checkbox0" type="checkbox" value="N">
                        <label for="checkbox0">N</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbx">
                        <input name="data[<?php echo $result['cq_id']; ?>]['red']"  id="inlineCheckbox2" type="checkbox">
                        <label for="inlineCheckbox2">Y</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline checkbx">
                        <input name="data[<?php echo $result['cq_id']; ?>]['alert']"  id="inlineCheckbox2" type="checkbox">
                        <label for="inlineCheckbox2">Y</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><a href="javascript:;" id="<?php echo $result['cq_id'];?>" class="save" name="<?php echo $result['cq_id']."_".$carePlansList['EveCarePlansList']['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a></td>
           </tr>
<?php  } } }else{?>
        <tr>
        <td colspan='8' class="text-center"> No Questions Found</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } }?>
```

Comment: if you are binding the event in a loop then it will bind it multiple times and it executes multiple obviously. Can you confirm you have not bound this event in the loop of any kind.

Comment: `$(document).on('click','.save',function(e){ e.stopPropagation();....othe code`

Comment: yes my data is in loop. i have multiple rows in loop buti want that row to be execute only once @jai

Comment: not working @Anant

Comment: @kunal take out the script from the loop if it is there.

Comment: @jai but i have to generate mulltiple tr each tr having save button

Comment: @kunal _take out the script_ only.

Comment: i update my question @Anant

Comment: @kunal  not html, jquery code. Btw don't remove html now. Just update your jquery code

Comment: my jquery code is show at top and i have added foreach data

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable at the top, before adding the click event listener. And then check for the running status before firing the ajax event.

```
var running = false;
$(document).on('click','.save',function() {
    if (running) {
        return false;
    }
    running = true;

    // Your ajax code here.
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success:function(resp){
            if(resp == "success"){
                alert("Data Saved");
            }
            running = false; // Note this line.
        },
        error : function (res) {
            console.log(res.responseText);
            running = false; // Note this line.
        }
    });
}
```

In the above code when the first time ajax fires it makes `running = true`. Until that ajax request finishes other misplaced ajax are blocked off.

Now this is not the right way to do it. But it is merely a fix. You should really look into your code and find out why is it firing multiple times? Are you clicking Save multiple times? Or what is the case?

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will have the disadvantage of disabling all `.save` buttons if one has fired. Maybe not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Correct... But for the time being... Once the ajax request is complete it will work again. Apache & PHP is not multi-threaded. So you already can't make 2 requests while the first request is not finished.

Comment: Actually nowdays most people use apache worker with PHP-FPM which is multi-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is the following:

```
$(document).on('click','.save:not(.running)',function() {
    var self = this;
    $(this).addClass("running");    
    // Your ajax code here.
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success:function(resp){
            if(resp == "success"){
                alert("Data Saved");
            }
        },
        error : function (res) {                
        },
        complete: function () { 
            $(self).removeClass("running");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lets make your code dynamic and reusable:** 
Step1: create function in helper

```
public function custom_plan_new_ajax($model, $selector = array()) {

    return $this->_View->Element('custom_plan_new_ajax', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'selector' => $selector
    ));
}
```

Step2 : Create custom_plan_new_ajax.ctp in Element directory add following function

```
$('#parentDivClassOrId').on('click','.save', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');  
        var model="UserModel";
        var c = confirm('Are you sure you want to changes status?');
        if (c == true) {
            var url = "test.php";             
            $.post(url, {id: id, model:model'}, //You can add here multiple data or send in serialize form
            function (resp) {                   
                var res = jQuery.parseJSON(resp);                  
                if (res.status == true) {
                   //your code

                } else {
                    //your code
                }
            });
        } else {

            return false;
        }

    });
```

Step3: Call in View file

```
$this->yourHelperName->custom_plan_new_ajax($model, $selector = array());
```

If still you have problem then share your script at khan.rashid777@gmail.com